# Ubuntu 18.04 stuck in login loop for one account

Tags: 18.04, permissions, login

since yesterday I am stuck in an infinite login loop for one of my users on Ubuntu 18.04. I can log in to another account but not the one I need to login to. I tried hours of different fixes from the web, but none of them worked. Among those are

- Reinstalling `gdm3`
- installing `lxsession`
- checking disk usage
- stopping and restarting the `gdm.service`
- `chmod 755 $HOME`
- `chmod a+rwx *` to grant all users full access
- Creating an .Xauthority file

I noticed that there is no .Xauthority file for this specific user. Unfortunately creating an empty .Xauthority file couldn't help. This issue happened after installing ROS and executing `sudo apt-get update && upgrade`.
My current version is 18.04.4 LTS and I believe this issue is connected to the update. However I am not sure what could be causing this.

I really appreciate any help and can elaborate more, if needed.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I just fixed it, maybe it can help anyone!

I had to uninstall the indicator-multiload tool by

```
sudo apt-get remove indicator-multiload
```